# Seamless data transfer between the system-wide clipboard and the sandbox inside of a Java applet via JNLP - possible?

Tags: java, applet, clipboard, copy-paste, jnlp

I am currently trying to implement the `ClipboardService` that's provided by the rather new JNLP API to access the system-wide clipboard inside of an Java applet that I launch via JNLP. What I want to do is, as soon as Ctrl+C is pressed, to copy the global clipboard's contents to the sandbox clipboard and vice versa (on Ctrl+V), just to make this integration as seamless as possible.

I already managed to actually get and set the contents of the system-wide clipboard. However I have no idea on where to find the sandbox clipboard that's used by default. The default Toolkit just provides access to the system clipboard that of course raises a security exception. I think there are ways to emulate this, but I'd really be happy to have a seamless solution that doesn't require any "hacks".

Comment: *"Seamless data transfer between the system-wide clipboard and the sandbox inside of a Java applet via JNLP - possible?"*  I doubt it.  You are effectively talking about intercepting and redirecting the keyboard input way from the system clipboard to a Java internal clipboard.  It seems that would require both trust and native code.

Comment: Actually retrieving and setting of the system-wide clipboard contents is possible through the JNLP ClipboardService: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ClipboardService.html However, I cannot find a simple solution to copy it to the clipboard used by the sandbox and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the system clip-board, you will get a security exception, unless your applet is signed.  If you want "seemless integration" between your app and the system, then you **do want** the system clip-board. Without access to this, you can only copy/paste within your applicaton.

As an example, see the [MLA citation generator](http://proctinator.com/citation/) that one of my students wrote with me last year. If this describes what you are trying to do, I'll post the relevant source code.

Comment: Yeah, there will be a security prompt only once when using the new JNLP API (ClipboardService). I already managed to access the system-wide clipboard for good through this but I've not found a way yet to synchronize its contents with the...like I call it...sandbox clipboard. What I am doing is to read the system clipboards contents on Ctrl+V, which issues the security prompt, and when answered with "Allow" I still don't have the contents in the currently focused text component. So, I guess, that I need to copy it to the sandbox clipboard or something like that first (or similar...).